# JS - Date string being returned as 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, date, return, console.log

I am attempting to get back the date using a function that returns the date n amount of days ago, however it seems to only return 'undefined'.

I have tried doing the `console.log()` in the final method which does appear to work, but I just can't understand what is going wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

See snipped below.

```js
var today = new Date();

function getDate(daysAgo) {
    var td = today;
    td.setDate(td.getDate() - daysAgo);
    getFormattedDate(td);
}

function getFormattedDate(date) {
  var dd = date.getDate();
  var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var yyyy = date.getFullYear();

  return yyyy+' '+mm+' '+dd;
}

console.log(getDate(1));
```

Comment: Your function has no `return` statement.

Comment: getDate or getFormattedDate? getDate calls getFormattedDate which does return...

Comment: Yes, but `getDate()` has no `return`.

Comment: @Pointy, you should have posted something with a little more explanation for the problem. See VicJordan's reply below.

Comment: I was looking for a good duplicate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing `return` in your `getDate()` function.

Check below:

```js
var today = new Date();

function getDate(daysAgo) {
    var td = today;
    td.setDate(td.getDate() - daysAgo);
    return getFormattedDate(td);
}

function getFormattedDate(date) {
  var dd = date.getDate();
  var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var yyyy = date.getFullYear();

  return yyyy+' '+mm+' '+dd;
}

console.log(getDate(1));
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware even Java wouldn't implicitly return anything…!?

Comment: @deceze agree with you. Function must have a return value or put log inside that function to print value or do some task.